# GraphServiceClient and its usage programmatically

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a group calendar using C# code and `GraphServiceClient`. I already got a `GraphServiceClient` object. But as soon as I call the below code, nothing happens. There is no response of the call. It just calls and forgets.

```
Group group = await graphClient.Groups.Request()

        //.WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount())

        .AddAsync(new Group

        {
            GroupTypes = new List<string> { "Unified" },
            DisplayName = "Test",
            Description = "Test",
            MailNickname = "Test",
            MailEnabled = false,
            SecurityEnabled = false
        });
```

Questions I have:

1. Is there any way to validate the `GraphServiceClient` object value?
2. Is there any log service which can help me understand why `graphClient.Groups.Request()` calls are not responding?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, it just works.

When debug it, I can get the group object:

[image]

By analyzing with Fiddler, I can double check that the group creating request get a success.

[image]

---

So:

### 1. Is there any way to validate the "GraphServiceClient object" value?

I do not think that you need to validate it. If the GraphServiceClient  object is invalid, you will get an error exception.

### 2. Is there any log service which can help me understand why "graphClient.Groups.Request()" calls are not responding?

Based on my test, it just works.  You may debug it or use Fiddler to capture the traffic to see if any request was made.

Comment: Yes, there was an authentication issue in my code. I have already fixed it. Thanks for response. Though i have one more query how to mock GraphServiceClient so that we can unit test Group Creation successfully without making call to graph instance. Any fake mocking and fake group creation unit test process available .?
To test :
await graphServiceClient.Groups.Request()
                      .AddAsync(new Group(...))
await graphServiceClient.Groups[addedGroup.Id].Owners.References.Request().AddAsync(owner);
await graphServiceClient.Groups[group.Id].Request().DeleteAsync();